# Why the coordinate vector of $\cos^2{x}$ is $[1, - 1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In an example of coodinatization and change of basis of linear algebra I have found that the coordinate vector of $\cos^2{x}$ relative to the ordered basis $(1, \sin^2{x})$ in the vector space $sp(1, \sin^2{x})$ is $[1, - 1]$. Why?

Comment: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$

Comment: @Jon Warneke, and $-1$? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Given the ordered basis $(\color{blue}{1}, \color{blue}{\sin^2 x})$, the vector that has coordinates $[\color{red}{1}, \color{red}{-1}]$ is
$$ \color{red}{1}\cdot\color{blue}1 + {(\color{red}{-1})\cdot\color{blue}{\sin^2 x} }= 1 - \sin^2 x = \cos^2 x $$